# Strange behavior by mixing vuejs 2.0 and Thymeleaf with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, thymeleaf

I've written some pages using Vuejs 2.0. In the static mode, all my components work and I could validate the design.
So, I've tried to integrate the source of these pages into a Web Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf but some rendering is not done.

A use case with the code below:

```
<selectpicker id="selectReg" title="Sélectionnez des régions"
              data-width="100%" v-bind:multiple="true"
              v-on:selected="selectRegion" v-on:unselected="unselectRegion">

    <option value="44">Alsace-Champagne-Ardenne-Lorraine</option>
    <option value="75">Aquitaine-Limousin-Poitou-Charentes</option>
    <option value="84">Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes</option>
</selectpicker>
```

The render result is:

```
<selectpicker id="selectReg" title="Sélectionnez des régions"
              data-width="100%" v-bind:multiple="true"
              v-on:selected="selectRegion" v-on:unselected="unselectRegion">

    Alsace-Champagne-Ardenne-Lorraine
    Aquitaine-Limousin-Poitou-Charentes
    Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes
</selectpicker>
```

The options are not kept.

Another problem is with a v-for attribute:

```
<optgroup label="Île-de-France">
    <option v-for="option in departementsFromRegion(11)" v-bind:value="option.value"
            v-bind:data-region="option.region">
        {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</optgroup>
```

As result, I've got an error in the browser console saying the option is not defined.

For information, I've configured Thymelead as LEGACYHTML5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the root of the problem. 
The Thymeleaf 2.x has some issues, so now I use the version 3.0.

For that, I've added these lines into my gradle configuration:

```
ext['thymeleaf.version'] = '3.0.0.RELEASE'
ext['thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version'] = '2.0.0'
```